# Removing last page of PDF using Python or Bash

Tags: python, linux, bash, pdf, edit

I have around 500 PDFs in which the last page is not required. Can I write a script using any tool using command line which can loop over all the files, remove the last page and save the new file?

I researched on the internet and pdftk was the most viable option, but it no longer works in Ubuntu.

Help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: As you say "pdftk no longer works on Ubuntu" it would be very helpful if you add more information about the OS you are using. Also it looks like [this post](https://askubuntu.com/q/221962/445311) provides lots of options (also scriptable ones) about modifying PDFs.

Comment: @a_guest I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: You can do it (in pure python) with https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pdfinfo` in order to get the number of pages from the pdf and `ghostscript` to delete the last one:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *.pdf
do
    page_nb=$(pdfinfo $file | awk '/^Pages/ { print $2 }')

    file_name=$(echo $file | cut -d'.' -f 1)

    gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=$(expr $page_nb - 1) -sOutputFile=$file_name"_without_last_page.pdf" $file
done
```

Answer (score 1):

I used the PyPDF2 and used following code. I was able to remove all the pages that I didn't need.

```
import PyPDF2 as pdf

pdf_file = open('361.pdf','rb')
read_file = pdf.PdfFileReader(pdf_file) #the file object that has been read

num_pages = read_file.numPages

wrote_pdf = pdf.PdfFileWriter() #the file object which is to be written

for pageNum in range(2,num_pages-1):
    pageObj = read_file.getPage(pageNum)
    wrote_pdf.addPage(pageObj)

output_pdf = open('361edited.pdf','wb')

wrote_pdf.write(output_pdf)
output_pdf.close()
pdf_file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could certainly do this with [PyPDF2](https://pypi.org/project/PyPDF2/1.26.0/). Read in all the pages then write out every page minus the last (using a for loop or something similar)